# Merging a commit that did rm --cached

Tags: git, merge

I created a git repository for a WordPress project and many commits later realised that I would only need some plugin and theme directories. I'd like to exclude all the other files from the repo.

I know I can remove files from the repo but keep them in the working directory with `git rm --cached`. I tried that but I didn't know how to merge that commit into other branches without losing the files in the merge.

1. How do I merge the removal without losing the files?
2. What will happen if I checkout older commits and then checkout HEAD again?
3. Or is there another way to remove the files that I didn't think of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest backing up the repository, in order to avoid mistakes. A simple `cp -r` should suffice. If you don't have enough drive space, run `git branch -av > branch_refs` so if anything goes wrong, you can easily restore the branches if anything goes wrong using `git reset`, without digging in the .git folder.

Now in order to avoid problems with question #2 (checking out older commits), I suggest using `filter-branch`. Notice that it will re-write your history, so if your work has been published (`push`ed) this is generally not a good idea.
First, remove the files so they are currently untracked (otherwise you'll lose their contents):

```
git rm --cached <file(s)>
git commit -m"removed tracking of unneeded files"
```

Replace `<file(s)>` with the files you wish to remove..
Now that the files are untracked, run the following command for the file(s) you wish to remove (replace `<file(s)>` as above):

```
git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch <file(s)>' -- --all
```

Now you should have an empty commit at the head (the "removed tracking.." one). Delete it:

```
git reset --soft HEAD^
```

That should do it, for the entire repo.

This is taken directly from the man page of `filter-branch`:

```
   Suppose you want to remove a file (containing confidential information
   or copyright violation) from all commits:

       git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm filename' HEAD

   However, if the file is absent from the tree of some commit, a simple
   rm filename will fail for that tree and commit. Thus you may instead
   want to use rm -f filename as the script.

   Using --index-filter with git rm yields a significantly faster version.
   Like with using rm filename, git rm --cached filename will fail if the
   file is absent from the tree of a commit. If you want to "completely
   forget" a file, it does not matter when it entered history, so we also
   add --ignore-unmatch:

       git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename' HEAD

   Now, you will get the rewritten history saved in HEAD.
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to to repeat `git rm --cached` operation in each branch and then update them all after you are done.

Comment: What do you mean by _update_? I suspect this solution wouldn't help to the second question in the original post.